# Adding panels using button handler in Sencha Touch

Tags: mobile, extjs, sencha-touch

I need a little help, I am building an app in Sencha Touch and I need to change the docked items within a container when a button is pressed. I assume this is the best way to alter the content within the app (i.e. switching between pages).

So far I have the following code -

```js
var App = new Ext.Application({
    name: 'Test',
    useLoadMask: true,
    launch: function () {

        // Toolbar
        Test.views.toolbar = new Ext.Toolbar({
            id: 'toolbar',
            title: 'Friend Pay'
        });

        // Content
        Test.views.content = new Ext.Panel({
            id: 'content',
            layout: 'fit',
            dockedItems: [{
                cls: 'copy',
                html: '<h2>Copy block</h2>'
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                id: 'buttonPanel',
                html: 'Request Payment',
                handler: function () {
                    // Link to newBlock panel
                }
            }]
        });

        // Content
        Test.views.newBlock = new Ext.Panel({
            id: 'content',
            layout: 'fit',
            dockedItems: [{
                cls: 'copy',
                html: '<h2>Test 2</h2>'
            }]
        });

        // Container
        Test.views.container = new Ext.Panel({
            id: 'container',
            layout: 'fit',
            dockedItems: [Test.views.toolbar, Test.views.content]
        });

        // Viewport - Entire screen
        Test.views.viewport = new Ext.Panel({
            fullscreen: true,
            scroll: 'vertical',
            items: [Test.views.container]
        });

    }
});
```

What function is required within the function() tag for the button handler to change the dockedItem within the container to be newBlock rather than content.

Many thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[addDocked](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/source/Panel1.html#method-Ext.lib.Panel-addDocked) and [removeDocked](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/source/Panel1.html#method-Ext.lib.Panel-removeDocked).

```
Test.views.viewport.removeDocked( Test.views.content )
Test.views.viewport.addDocked( Test.views.newBlock )
```

It seems a little odd you are adding content into `dockedItems` though, maybe you ment to add them to the normal `items` collection?
Either way, checkout everything available for `Ext.Panel` in the [main api docs](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext.lib.Panel) to familiarise yourself with the standard component functions.